# changing the viewmode of textfield depending on current language

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

am trying to change a edittext's icon from right to left depending on the language ..

I'm using https://github.com/MoathOthman/MOLH for localization ..

and am trying to do it like this:

```
     override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


        let image2 = UIImage(named: "username")
        let border2 = CALayer()
        let width2 = CGFloat(1.0)
        let color2 = UIColor(red:0.80, green:0.80, blue:0.80, alpha:1.0)
        border2.borderColor = color2.cgColor
        border2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.email.frame.size.height - width2, width: self.email.frame.size.width, height: self.email.frame.size.height)
        border2.borderWidth = width2
        let paddingView2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 20))
        let paddingImage2 = UIImageView()
        paddingImage2.image = image2
        paddingImage2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        paddingImage2.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
        paddingView2.addSubview(paddingImage2)

        let image4 = UIImage(named: "password")
        let border4 = CALayer()
        let width4 = CGFloat(1.0)
        let color4 = UIColor(red:0.80, green:0.80, blue:0.80, alpha:1.0)
        border4.borderColor = color4.cgColor
        border4.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.password.frame.size.height - width4, width: self.password.frame.size.width, height: self.password.frame.size.height)
        border4.borderWidth = width4
        let paddingView4 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 20))
        let paddingImage4 = UIImageView()
        paddingImage4.image = image4
        paddingImage4.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        paddingImage4.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 0, width: 22, height: 17)
        paddingView4.addSubview(paddingImage4)

        if MOLHLanguage.isArabic(){
            print("arabic")
            self.email.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
            self.email.rightView = paddingView2
            self.password.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
            self.password.rightView = paddingView4
        }else{
            print("english")
            self.email.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
            self.email.leftView = paddingView2
            self.password.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
            self.password.leftView = paddingView4
        }

        self.email.layer.addSublayer(border2)
        self.email.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.password.layer.addSublayer(border4)
        self.password.layer.masksToBounds = true

}
```

This will always display the icon in the left side of the textfield .. even though its entering the and printing the current language correctly .. in english and arabic it will be on the leftview of the textfield ..

Why this happening? and how to solve it?

Comment: I think you also need to set the text alignment of text field-  textfield.textAlignment = Language.isArabicLanguage ? .right : .left         }

Comment: @shivi_shub am actually doing this but delete it from the posted code .. and its working the textalignment is changing depending on the language correctly ..